# Преобразование текста в html

Tags: php

Есть текст

```
<p>Интернет-магазин  занимается продажей готовых букетов, предоставляет услуги по созданию и доставке цветочных композиций, цветочных корзин и свадебных букетов. </p>
```

При выводе в echo отображается вместе с тегами. 
Как преобразовать его в html ?

Comment: При выводе куда ? Отображаются где, в браузере ? Если да - то это очень странно, браузер должен сам обработать все теги, если вы их конечно на стороне браузера JS в innerText не загоняете. Приведите пример кода на котором явно можно увидеть данный эффект.

Comment: В браузере. 
Выводится просто через echo

Comment: Хм. Т.е. просто `$string="<p>текст</p>"; echo $string;` и никаких больше преобразований не происходит ? И из браузера эта страница просто открывается указанием ее url в адресной строке и какой нибудь ajax не используется ?

Comment: Не совсем ясно "При выводе в echo отображается вместе с тегами. Как преобразовать его в html ?" Тоесть эта строчка на выходе должна будет выведена в браузере и он ее должен обработать, тоесть вывести "Интернет-магазин  занимается продажей готовых букетов, предоставляет услуги по созданию и доставке цветочных композиций, цветочных корзин и свадебных букетов. " в стиле пожирневшего?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strip_tags('<p>Интернет-магазин  занимается продажей готовых букетов, предоставляет услуги по созданию и доставке цветочных композиций, цветочных корзин и свадебных букетов. </p>')
```

удалит все теги

```
html_special_chars('<p>Интернет-магазин  занимается продажей готовых букетов, предоставляет услуги по созданию и доставке цветочных композиций, цветочных корзин и свадебных букетов. </p>')
```

экранирует

ну а теги

```
<pre>.....kode....</pre>
```

вывидут так как есть

Comment: прошу прощения что влез , но <pre> и <code> как они вообще работают ?

Comment: Ну ваш ответ мне не помог.... Не работает так..

Comment: header('Content-type:text/html')